# Why is sorting not taking O(n log (n)) in time

Tags: c++, sorting, time, performance-testing

In the following snippet the time consumption of `std::sort`. This should take [O(nlog(n))](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) time. `std::chrono` is used solely measuring `std::sort`.

I compiled the following code with the Intel compiler 18.0.3 with optimization level `-O3`. I use Redhat6.

```
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::random_device dev;
    std::mt19937 rng(dev());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> dist(std::numeric_limits<int>::min(),
                                                                  std::numeric_limits<int>::max());

    int ret = 0;

    const unsigned int max = std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max();
    for (auto j = 1u; j < max; j *= 10) {
        std::vector<int> vec;

        vec.reserve(j);

        for (int i = 0; i < j; ++i) {
            vec.push_back(dist(rng));
        }

        auto t_start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
        const auto t_end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        const auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(t_end - t_start).count();
        std::cout << "Time measurement: j= " << j << " took " << duration << " seconds.\n";
        ret + vec[0];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

The output of this program is

```
Time measurement: j= 1 took 1.236e-06 seconds.
Time measurement: j= 10 took 5.583e-06 seconds.
Time measurement: j= 100 took 1.0145e-05 seconds.
Time measurement: j= 1000 took 0.000110649 seconds.
Time measurement: j= 10000 took 0.00142651 seconds.
Time measurement: j= 100000 took 0.00834339 seconds.
Time measurement: j= 1000000 took 0.098939 seconds.
Time measurement: j= 10000000 took 0.938253 seconds.
Time measurement: j= 100000000 took 10.2398 seconds.
Time measurement: j= 1000000000 took 114.214 seconds.
Time measurement: j= 1410065408 took 163.824 seconds.
```

[image]

This seems to be very close to linear behaviour.

Why is `std::sort` requiring `O(n)` rather than `O(nlog(n))`?

Comment: Big-O notation is about *complexity* and not specific timing.

Comment: O(n*log(n)) is the worst-case that the standard allows.  Standard library implementations are still allowed to make optimizations.  Some sorting algorithms (especially those that work with numbers) approach O(n).

Comment: In your data, 10^9 elements sorted in 114.214, but on your graph, it's > 160 seconds? Could you please clarify?

Comment: In big scale chart of `n log n` looks like linear function: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+log+x+from+2+to+100000

Comment: @vahancho. I missed the last line for copy and paste. Post has been corrected

Comment: @schorsch312, I see, thanks.

Comment: Please show an example of the graph that you expected instead.

Comment: However "obvious" the answer, this has to be one of the best time-related question asked this year.

Comment: @Bathsheba What's good about it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Well written, good test case, pretty graph. What more could you want in a question?

Comment: @Bathsheba A valid premise would be a good start. OP didn't even bother to look up what the graph _should_ look like (which happens to be exactly what they're getting)...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Unless you had a warped childhood you'd be forgiven in thinking that x log (x) was more curvy than it actually is.

Comment: Also take into account that small test cases are biased due to the size of the cache.

Comment: @Bathsheba We do require some prior research here at Stack Overflow, not just blind guesses :)

Comment: I would be interested to see a fine resolution version of this graph for small values of _n_. Lets say upto 12Mb of data.

Comment: @kvantour: Well the code is there ready for appropriate adaption.

Comment: @kvantour , schorsch312: that's why [such graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth) should always be plotted [at log-log scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log%E2%80%93log_plot) instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The graph you present is a good fit for `y = x log (x)`. Compared to `x`, `log(x)` has a small effect. I conject your results would pass a chi square for `x log (x)` with good significance.

There are no surprises here.

This is a touchstone for your appreciation that O(n log n) isn't much worse than O(n).

Comment: Like i wrote in comment: In big scale chart of `n log n` looks like linear function: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+log+x+from+2+to+100000

Comment: @MarekR: I should jolly well hope so!

Comment: @MarekR , Bathsheba: [such graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth) should always be plotted [at log-log scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log%E2%80%93log_plot) instead: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log-log+plot+x+log+x+from+2+to+100000